# How to use a D-Link usb network adapter on debian

Tags: debian, wifi

I have a Debian (squeeze) desktop, and I need to use a D-Link 150 USB Wireless Network Adapter. So far I've done this:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:3c18 D-Link Corp.
...
```

After looking for a solution in google, I found that I needed to install the following package:

```
firmware-ralink_0.28+squeeze1_all.deb
```

I've installed it, but Debian doesn't want to find the adapter. When I run `lsmod`, I can't find what I'm supposed to find: `rt2870sta`

Can you point me in the right direction?

---

A little more data.

I checked `ifconfig`, and there's not any wireless adapter detected by debian:

```
# ifconfig
eth0 ...
lo ...
```

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
#NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: What happens if you `modprobe rt2870sta`?

Comment: @Renan Now it appears on `lsmod`, but I still can't use it... network manager doesn't recognize any network

Comment: This is a cross-post from http://superuser.com/questions/502482/how-to-use-a-d-link-usb-network-adapter-on-debian

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I've posted it in both sites... I didn't know which one would be a better place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your device is not supported by rt2870sta (or rt2800usb as it is called in newer kernels).

See lists of supported devices for [rt2870sta](http://wiki.debian.org/rt2870sta#supported) and [rt2800usb](http://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb#supported)

Comment: Debian Linux, kernel version 2.6.32-5-amd64

Comment: judging from usb id you posted, the answer is that your device is currently not supported